# Joomla Database query column params OS Events Manager

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I am using OS Events Manager, and I need to show query from a table column to show the "field_speaker" which is the under the params column in OS Events Manager. I have this code:
`

```
$query   = $db->getQuery(true)
->select('a.*')
->from('#__eb_speakers AS a')
->innerJoin('#__eb_events AS b ON a.id = b.speaker_id')
->where('b.event_id = ' . $event->id)
->order('b.id');
$db->setQuery($query);
$speakers = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($speakers); ?>'
```

I don't know how to call the column params "field_speaker" as shown in the image I provided... If you look at my code I only have the eb_events-which is where everything is going wrong I guess???

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know a little PHP-obviously not enough...
 Sam[image]

Comment: So, the value of column `params`, is a JSON dictionary, from which you want to pull the value of the key `field_speaker`?

Comment: Terminus-I believe so yes. This events manager has a calendar page that shows just general info, but I want to also show the speaker's name (which comes from the params column in eb_events to my file.

Comment: Thats a paid component i suppose. Unless I have a look at all the code I can help. If you can upload somewhere the entire code and PM me then I will be able to help you out,

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be only interested in the `params` column, so only write that column in the SELECT clause and use `loadColumn()` to access the data (generate a 1-dimensional array for simpler handling).

https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Single_Column_Results

If you want more columns than `params`, you should name them explicitly in your query, and use a different method to collect the result set.  (See the link above)

My untested suggestion:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('a.params')                 // only ask for what you intend to use
            ->from('#__eb_speakers AS a')
            ->innerJoin('#__eb_events AS b ON a.id = b.speaker_id')
            ->where('b.event_id = ' . (int)$event->id)   // for security cast as an integer
            ->order('b.id');
$db->setQuery($query);
if (!$params = $db->loadColumn()) {
    echo "No Data Found for " . (int)$event->id;
} else {
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        $speakers[] = json_decode($param, true)['field_speaker']; // I assume this key always exists
    }
}
var_export($speakers);  // this will show you the isolated speaker data
```

p.s. When you have Joomla-based questions, please post them in Joomla Stack Exchange so that that community has some new stuff to chew on.

Comment: p.s. My `#__eb_events` table doesn't have a `event_id` column.  My `#__eb_registrants` table does though.